# How do I keep variable pointers that only hold const values

Tags: c, pointers, syntax, constants

I have to work with tables like these in my code:

```
const char *scale_table [4][8] = {
{ "0.0094","0.00752","0.00564","0.0047","0.00376","0.0031333333","0.0025066667","0.00188"},
{ "0.0188","0.01504","0.01128","0.0094","0.00752","0.0062666667","0.0050133333","0.00376"},
{ "0.0376","0.03008","0.02256","0.0188","0.01504","0.0125333333","0.0100266667","0.00752"},
{ "0.0752","0.06016","0.04512","0.0376","0.03008","0.0250666667","0.0200533333","0.01504"},
```

};

I have some char* variables that only get assigned with the instruction

```
entry = scale_table[i][j];
```

Which causes the warning "assignment discards 'const' qualifier from pointer target type". The variables are obviously not const, and I do not want to cast const pointer into non-const as the strings are never modified. i.e. The pointer variables are not const but will always point to constant values.

What is the correct syntax for this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Declare `entry` as `const char *` (or, equivalently, `char const *`).  This is a non-constant pointer to constant characters: you can change the pointer itself to make it point to different characters, but you can't modify the actual characters through the pointer.

A constant *pointer* — one that you can't change to point to something else — would be `char * const`, or `char const * const` to prevent both the pointer *and* the pointed-to characters from being modified.

The easiest way to read types involving `const` is from right to left:  `char const *` is a pointer to constant `char`, and `char * const` is a constant pointer to `char`.  The `const` keyword always applies to the type on its left.  (As a special case, if it's written at the beginning so that there's nothing to its left, it applies to the type on its right instead.  That's why `const char` is equivalent to `char const`.)